# Can't find my iPhone app in search results

Tags: iphone, app-store

The app status is `Ready for Sale` and there is a working direct link to it in iTunes. However the search either with keywords or by the app name from the iTunes top left corner does not bring any result. It is listed in website when I manually browse to category.

The search however bring result on iPhone device App Store app. Just curious why my app is not found through the website search.

Answer (score 16):

It may take a while until the app shows up in the search. How long ago did you receive the "Ready for Sale" notification?

Comment: Then I'd suggest waiting some longer. My last submission took over 24 hours to be available via the search field.

Comment: In my cause it took **48 hours** since my status changed to "Ready for Sale"

Answer (score 9):

Mostly the app is visible in the iTunes App Store (on the PC, NOT on the iPhone) before on the iPhone. If it takes longer than 24 hours, I would consider contacting Apple but before you have an answer from them your app will probably be Live so... Just be patient, it can take some hours... But again, check iTunes on your Mac/PC if you can find your app there, in my case it was always like that, first iTunes then App Store..

Good luck with your app!

Comment: It's strange, because I picked some other apps which are there for quite long time and searched, still can't find them.